# AS3: How create line gallery

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, gallery, line

I'm trying to create a line gallery: where all photos are set next to another, but the photos have different widths. I have to put the `x` loacation in `function callThumbs()`, but I get the needed `widths` in function thumbLoaded(e:Event).

I put them into `variables` `minWidth` and `miniHeight`. I've seen some examples with a `callback` function but i can't implement this to my code. Can anyone help?

```
var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("images.xml"));
myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

var my_thumb_width:Number;
var my_thumb_height:Number;
var my_images:XMLList;
var my_total:Number;

var currentX:Number = 0;

var miniWidth:Number;
var miniHeight:Number;

if (stage)
{
    initialize();
}
else
{
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,initialize);
}

    function initialize(e:Event = null):void
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,initialize);
    stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
    stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
    stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE,onResizeDoc);
    stage.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE));
    stage.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onRemove);
    resizeMyDoc();
}

function onResizeDoc(event:Event = null):void
{
    resizeMyDoc();
}

function resizeMyDoc():void
{
    var sw:Number = stage.stageWidth;
    var sh:Number = stage.stageHeight;

    if (stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN)
    {
        //code nor relevant to my issue
    }
    else
    {
        //code nor relevant to my issue
    }
}

function processXML(e:Event):void
{
    var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);

    my_thumb_width = myXML. @ WIDTH;
    my_thumb_height = myXML. @ HEIGHT;
    my_images = myXML.IMAGE;
    my_total = my_images.length();

    preloaders_mc = new MovieClip();
    preloaders_mc.x = miniaturki.x;
    preloaders_mc.y = miniaturki.y;
    addChild(preloaders_mc);

    miniaturki.buttonMode = true;

    callThumbs();

    myXMLLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
    myXMLLoader = null;
}

function callThumbs():void
{
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < my_total; i++)
    {
        var thumb_url = my_images[i].@THUMB;;
        var thumb_loader = new Loader();
        thumb_loader.load(new URLRequest(thumb_url));
        thumb_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thumbLoaded);

        thumb_loader.name = i;
    }
}

function thumbLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    var my_thumb:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);
    miniaturki.addChild(my_thumb);

    miniWidth = my_thumb.width;
    miniHeight = my_thumb.height;

    trace(miniWidth);
    trace(miniHeight);

    my_thumb.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thumbLoaded);
}

function onRemove(e:Event=null):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onResizeDoc);
}
```

Here are the two `functions` I was talking aboute;

```
function callThumbs():void
{
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < my_total; i++)
    {
        var thumb_url = my_images[i].@THUMB;;
        var thumb_loader = new Loader();
        thumb_loader.load(new URLRequest(thumb_url));
        thumb_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thumbLoaded);

        thumb_loader.name = i;
    }
}

function thumbLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    var my_thumb:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);
    miniaturki.addChild(my_thumb);

    my_tweens[Number(my_thumb.name)]=new Tween(my_thumb, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 0,1,0.5, true);

    miniWidth = my_thumb.width; // traced width is the one that I need
    miniHeight = my_thumb.height;

    trace(miniWidth);
    trace(miniHeight);

    my_thumb.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thumbLoaded);
}
```

The second issue is with the `resize handler`. When i remove him then the pictures are `loaded` with any problem, but when the `resize handler` stays, then i have first to `resize` the window to see the pictures. Earlier when i've got the same issue, then I only needed to add a `DispatchEvent`: `stage.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE));` , but i added it and the problem is still there

Can anyone help!

Comment: SO is not about giving 100+ lines of code to people so they mess up with it and figures out what you want to do. Please show us the *minimal* code for reproducing your problem and explain how you tried to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your loaders in an array - store everything like that in arrays.

Create array at top:

```
var aThumbs:Array = new Array();
```

Push your loaders in as you add them to stage:

```
var my_thumb:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);
miniaturki.addChild(my_thumb);
aThumbs.push(my_thumb);
```

Then use the array to reference like this:

```
iGetThumbWidth = aThumbs[i].width;
```